# OpenCV 3.0 Python SVM example

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, svm, opencv3.0

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/digits.py is the example of SVM in opencv python 3.0 can anyone please explain what is done inside the process_hog() function inside the loop .Thanks in advance!

```
def preprocess_hog(digits):
    samples = []
    for img in digits:
        gx = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_32F, 1, 0)
        gy = cv2.Sobel(img, cv2.CV_32F, 0, 1)
        mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(gx, gy)
        bin_n = 16
        bin = np.int32(bin_n*ang/(2*np.pi))
        bin_cells = bin[:10,:10], bin[10:,:10], bin[:10,10:], bin[10:,10:]
        mag_cells = mag[:10,:10], mag[10:,:10], mag[:10,10:], mag[10:,10:]
        hists = [np.bincount(b.ravel(), m.ravel(), bin_n) for b, m in zip(bin_cells, mag_cells)]
        hist = np.hstack(hists)

        # transform to Hellinger kernel
        eps = 1e-7
        hist /= hist.sum() + eps
        hist = np.sqrt(hist)
        hist /= norm(hist) + eps

        samples.append(hist)
    return np.float32(samples)
```

## Edit

If I use hog.compute() instead

```
def preprocess_hog(digits):
    samples = []
    hog=cv2.HOGDescriptor()
    idx=0
    for img in digits:
        print idx
        idx+=1
        samples.append(hog.compute(img))
    return np.float32(samples)
```

It gives this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "handGT.py", line 125, in <module>
    samples = preprocess_hog(digits)
  File "handGT.py", line 110, in preprocess_hog
    return np.float32(samples)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: I'm going with: it's computing the [Histogram of Oriented Gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients) (single block) feature for each digit :D

Comment: I get that .. But why not just hog.compute() ?

Comment: I _think_ because it's computing only a single block HoG, not the full featured HoG descriptor (a lot of overlapping blocks with interpolation).

Comment: ok so If I want to extract hog features for anything larger than 10x10 ?? that won't fit . Can you suggest me any documentation where I could find the details of all the steps that is done her??

Comment: actually I don't know. For anything larger you should be ok with hog.compute()

Comment: but it gives error if I convert the hog of each training image List to np.array()